# select [combobox value] & "text"

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, vba

I am trying to build SELECT statement in Access VBA, based on value chosen by user in ComboBox.

Example :

`"SELECT [8_SV_RT] FROM DATA WHERE condition = value`

I need `8` to be dependent on ComboBox value from form. (8,10,12 ....)

The name of ComboBox is `DN`, and I created string `COL = "_SV_RT"`

So far I have :

`"SELECT [DN] & '" & COL & "' FROM DATA WHERE condition = value`

It returns value `8_SV_RT` to ComboBox, which I want to use after SELECT statement, but not as result. I must be missing some syntax or something? Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT [" & Me.MyComboBox & "_SV_RT] FROM DATA WHERE condition = value"
```

---

**EDIT:**
To use the exact object names from the question *(before Siddharth edited it, I over-read that the combobox is named `DN`)* and to take Siddharth's *(now deleted)* comment into consideration:

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim COL As String

COL = "_SV_RT"
SQL = "SELECT [" & DN & COL & "] FROM DATA WHERE condition = value"
```

Comment: If `COL = "_SV_RT"`, then the result is the same. Using `COL` is not necessary just to get this query right. Maybe he needed `COL` for something else anyway, but I supposed that he only added it because he thought it's necessary.

Comment: thanks ! i guess i'm looking on it for too long and didn't think of this simple solution